# ruby on rails devise gem where is the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, devise

I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Everything works.

I create a new user in the page: email, password, works fine.

I can login with the password and email, I just wanna know where it is saving that, I tried find the sqlite database but I could not find anything.

```
$sqlite3
sqlite> .databases
seq  name                  file                                                      
---  ---------------      ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main
```

I would like know where it is saving the users and passwords?

Why cant I see a database there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devise stores its users' info in the Rails database. You can see which database Rails is using by looking at the file PROJECT_ROOT/config/database.yml .

To see the user entries, connect to that database and try the following query:
`SELECT * FROM users;`

Comment: thanks for your message:  found this:


  database: db/development.sqlite3


i tried run : sqlite3 and after .databases , but i still not seeing any databases there, do you know why?

thank you.

Comment: How about running `sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3` from your project root directory?

Comment: works perfect thank you, do you know why i cant see the database just runing sqlite3, .databases ? if i run these commands just show me 0 databases.

Comment: sqlite stores its databases in files. If you don't tell it which file to look at it won't know where to find the database.